# java.lang.nullPonterException when using an object's method

Tags: java, arrays, object, parameters, nullpointerexception

Hi I've got this object called Rectangle, here's the code:

```
class Rectangle{
    private double length, breath, area, perimeter;
    private static double largestArea;
    public void setSideDetails(double length, double breath){
        this.length = length;
        this.breath = breath;
    }

    public double getArea(){
        area = length*breath;
        return area;
    }

    public double getPerimeter(){
        perimeter = 2*(length+breath);
        return perimeter;
    }

    public static void setLargestArea(double areas[]){
        for(int i = 0; i < areas.length; i++){
            if(areas[i] > largestArea){
                largestArea = areas[i];
            }
        }
    }

    public static double getLargestArea(){
        return largestArea;
    }

    public void drawRectangle(){
        System.out.print(" ");
        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
            System.out.print("_");
        }
        System.out.println();
        for(int i = 0; i < breath; i++){
            System.out.print("|");
            for(int j = 0; j < length; j++){
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.println("|");
        }
        System.out.print(" ");
        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
            System.out.print("¯");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

and the class that's using it:

```
import java.util.*;
class UsingRectangle{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        in.useDelimiter("\n");

        int number = 0;
        boolean isError = false;
        String units;

        System.out.print("How many rectangles do you want to create? ");
        do{
            try{
                number = in.nextInt();
                number = Math.abs(number);
                isError = false;
            }catch(InputMismatchException e){
                System.out.println("Your input was not accepted. Please try again.");
                in.next();
                isError = true;
            }
        }while(isError);
        do{
            isError = false;
            System.out.print("Please enter the units in mm, cm or m: ");
            units = in.next();
            if(!(units.equalsIgnoreCase("mm"))&&!(units.equalsIgnoreCase("cm"))&&!(units.equalsIgnoreCase("m"))){
                System.out.println("Your input was not accepted. Please try again.");
                isError = true;
            }
        }while(isError);

        Rectangle[] r = new Rectangle[number]; //The actual rectangles are instanceiated here.
        double areas[] = new double[number]; //This will be used to collect the areas to be sent to a static method.

        for(int i = 0; i < r.length; i++){
            double length = 0;
            double breath = 0;
            do{
                isError = false;
                try{
                    System.out.print("Please enter the length of Rectangle "+(i+1)+": ");
                    length = Math.abs(in.nextInt());
                }catch(InputMismatchException e){
                    System.out.println("Your input was not accepted. Please try again.");
                    in.next();
                    isError = true;
                }
            }while(isError);
            do{
                isError = false;
                try{
                    System.out.print("Please enter the breath of Rectangle "+(i+1)+" ");
                    breath = Math.abs(in.nextInt());
                }catch(InputMismatchException e){
                    System.out.println("Your input was not accepted. Please try again.");
                    in.next();
                    isError = true;
                }
            }while(isError);
            r[i].setSideDetails(length, breath);
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < r.length; i++){
            r[i].drawRectangle();
            areas[i] = r[i].getArea();
            System.out.println("Area: "+areas[i]+units+"2   Perimeter: "+r[i].getPerimeter()+units);
        }

        System.out.print("The largest area is:  ");
        Rectangle.setLargestArea(areas);
        System.out.print(Rectangle.getLargestArea());
    }
}
```

My Problem is this:

where it says `r[i].setSideDetails(length,breath);` a runtime error - `java.lang.nullPointerException null` is made. I have no idea what's causing this. Any searches haven't bore fruit and I would like to know the cause, effect and prevention apart from how to solve it.

Thanks

BTW I'm an A-Level Student sitting for the exams in two years time, so don't act like I should have known these if I am a professional.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you've just declared the `Rectangle[] r = new Rectangle[number];` and haven't initialized the elements in this array. By default each element of the array would be `null` giving you the NPE when trying to call a method on it. Initialize each element in the array before calling methods on it.

*Example:*

```
Rectangle[] r = new Rectangle[number];
for(int i = 0; i < r.length; i++){
    r[i] = new Rectangle(); // You can use either this or some other constructor you have.
}
```

Comment: Just to add a bit more clarity here - When you create an array of a certain object type, it creates the space for those objects to be stored, but you actually have to initialize those objects individually and store them in the array.  R.J.'s example does exactly this.

Comment: Wow, thanks. It seems so simple. To be honest this is my first time working with Object Arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a NullPointerException because the reference `r[i]` points to nothing/`null`. So you have to instantiate `Rectangle` objects and put it into the array.

```
for(int i = 0; i < r.length; i++)
    r[i] = new Rectangle(); // creating a new Rectangle object here
```